# matlab - defining different color and shape symbol

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I'm trying to build a loop in which the color and the shape of each symbol is dependent of a value1 and value2 respectively.

for example

name x-coord y-coord value1 value2

p1    x1       y1      1      0

p2    x2       y2      0      1

if value1=1 p1 color is blue, and if value2=0 p1 shape is a circle

if value1=0 p1 color is red, and if value2=1 p2 shape is a square

i know how to write an if loop, but i'm not sure how to do 2 if loops

I appreciate any help

Comment: If you have the statistics toolbox, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602230/how-do-i-plot-this-matlab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but your question isn't very clear. I've answered with what I think you want.

If this is a totally wrong response, then perhaps it would help us if you could rephrase the question.

```
if value1==0;
    p1color='b';
    p1shape='o';
else
    p1color='r'
    p1shape='s';
end

if value2==1;
    p2color='b';
    p2shape='o';
else
    p2shape='r';
    p2shape='s';
end

plot(x1,y1,[p1color p1shape],x2,y2,[p2color p2shape]);
```

That may not be exactly what you're looking for... but do you get the idea?